# Deleted copy constructor results in deleted default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, deleted-functions

This code will not compile with gcc 4.7.0:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(const Base&) = delete;
}; 

class Derived : Base
{
public:
    Derived(int i) : m_i(i) {}

    int m_i;
};
```

The error is:

```
c.cpp: In constructor `Derived::Derived(int)´:
c.cpp:10:24: error: no matching function for call to `Base::Base()´
c.cpp:10:24: note: candidate is:
c.cpp:4:2: note: Base::Base(const Base&) <deleted>
c.cpp:4:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

In other words, the compiler does not generate a default constructor for the base class, and instead tries to call the *deleted* copy constructor as the only available overload.

Is that normal behavior?

Comment: Yes, because if any constructor is *user-declared*, the default-constructor is suppressed.

Comment: By why is deleting a constructor considered to be a declaration of a constructor? This is counter intuitive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C++11 §12.1/5 states:

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).

Your `Base(const Base&) = delete;` counts as a user-declared constructor, so it suppresses generation of the implicit default constructor. The workaround is of course to declare it:

```
Base() = default;
```

Comment: Why would a deleted constructor count as a declaration of a constructor? This does not make sense to me. A deleted constructor explicitly states the intention to not allow the definition of such constructor (defaulted or not).

Comment: I found this: [ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N2346](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2346.htm#delete) that states that all lookup and overload resolution happens *before* the deleted definition is noted, hence this answer is correct.